# How to show Validation Summary in MessageBox?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I try to do dynamic validation summary. As you see [this picture](http://oi43.tinypic.com/eqcmtx.jpg), I want to show validation summary as in bubble next to button. However I can't.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Yönetim Giriş";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LoginLayout.cshtml";
    var a = Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Hatalı giriş. Lütfen tekrar deneyiniz.");
 }
```

I can get my validation summary with using `var a` . I want to show this message in bubble or in message box.

-EDİT-

```
<tr> <td align="right" colspan="2">
    @Html.DialogFormLink("Şifremi Unuttum", Url.Action("SifreUnuttum"), "Şifre Hatırlama", "ProfileContainer", Url.Action("Login"))
     <input type="submit" value="Log In" onclick="javascript:alert();" />
</td> </tr> </table>



<script>
    function alert(){
       alert(@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Hatalı giriş. Lütfen tekrar deneyiniz."))
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You say something like: alert(@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Hatalı giriş. Lütfen tekrar deneyiniz.")) Isn;t working? /* I can't open picture */

Comment: yes. when I click submit button. it doesn't appear.

Comment: You need to show more code. I can see no submit button in you snippet

Comment: Added button and script code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change name of you function:

```
<script>
    function alert(){
       alert(@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Hatalı giriş. Lütfen tekrar deneyiniz."))
    }
</script>
```

you named you function alert() which is function of alert window in js.
So you are making infinite loop for calls.
You got stackoverflow :P

use Ctrl+shif+J
you can find js errors there

Comment: thanks. and now I can see alert window but there is nothing written in the box.